# Can't get form to post or query is not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn about $_SESSION variables and I've been following some tutorials I've found online.
I've created a form and I'm posting it back to the same page but the query fails. I have a table 'users' and I've added 'bob' to the userlogin field and 'bob' to the user_passwrd field. When I execute I get the error from the if/else statement that the query failed.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I would really appreciate some help on this.
I don't know if the form is not posting or where the problem might be.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
    include ('admin_pages/sql_pages/sql_connect_L.inc.php');

    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
    $passwrd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwrd']);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userlogin = '$login' AND user_passwrd = '$passwrd'");

    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($count == 1)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = '$login';
        header('location: admin_pages/dashboard.php');
    }

    else
    {
        echo " Your query failed";
    }

?>

    <form method="post" action="logintest.php">
      Username: <input name="login" type="text" class="login_fields" />
      <br/>
      Password: <input name="passwrd" type="password" class="login_fields" />
      <br/>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" class="long_button" id="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

I've tried several different things and I can't get the desired results.

Cheers

Comment: btw, you don't supply the error message.

Comment: It tells me "Your query failed" from the else statement. I also get errors from the if statement about the session_start:  Cannot send session cookie  Cannot send session cache limiter - 
Cannot modify header information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step in debugging is, check your SQL string:

```
$sqlText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userlogin = '$login' AND user_passwrd = '$passwrd'";
echo $sqlText;
$sql = mysql_query($sqlText) or die(mysql_error());
```

I noticed, you have minor issue in your code:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = '$login';
```

will result in `$_SESSION['login']` having value of `$login` literally. Not the value of `$login`. To fix it, change your code into:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = "$login";
//or to be simpler:
$_SESSION['login'] = $login;
```

Why is that? [here's the explanations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php#39194).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the code and when I put the values 'bob' in username and password it echos those values. So, what should I do next? I'm very new at this and trying to learn.

Comment: Thanks again. I've made that change, but I get errors from the $_SESSION stuff such as: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at I:\xampp\htdocs\logintest.php:8) in I:\xampp\htdocs\logintest.php on line 15

Comment: FYI, session_start() must be set BEFORE any server output. Not even single space or `enter`. Otherwise, you'll get error: `Cannot send session cookie Cannot send session cache limiter - Cannot modify header information`